# Getting curl-L invalid syntax when running on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, yolo

I'm trying to create a object detection module using YOLO V5 following this tutorial
[YT Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ciy1J97dbY0&t=352s)

In this they have used google colab but I want to create it on jupyter note book.
[image]
I get the above error when trying to get the data set from roboflow.
Please help!

Comment: That tutorial is a bit outdated. It's probably better to use the roboflow `pip` package method (in python) which is the default nowadays vs the shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an exclamation before curl.

```
!curl -L
```